# Pull for each element of an embedded hash in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

In MongoDB, I have documents defined like:

```
{
    'foo': {
        'a': [1,2,3,4,5],
        'b': [1,5,9],
        'c': [2,5,7]
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a simple way to remove, for instance, the number `2` in each list where it appears. In this example, that would update this document to:

```
{
    'foo': {
        'a': [1,3,4,5],
        'b': [1,5,9],
        'c': [5,7]
    }
}
```

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it using [atomic updates](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating), because of [positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) will update only first matched item in nested array. You can make multiple update only for root level fields.
There is only one solution: load document, update nested array and save.